# OpenLayers 3 - Cesium (ol is not defined)

Tags: openlayers, cesium

I am trying to get Cesium working in my OpenLayers 3 application.

I am using ol3-cesium-v1.7 from: https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium/releases
My application was using OpenLayers 3.82.

I removed the call to ol.js and replaced it with this:

```
<script src="/resources/api/Cesium/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/api/Cesium/ol3cesium-debug.js"></script>
```

In my code I have this:

```
                map = new ol.Map({
                    target: 'map',
                    renderer: 'canvas',
                    layers: mapLayersArray,
                    controls: ol.control.defaults({
                        attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                            collapsible: false
                        })
                    }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
                    view: new ol.View({
                        center: ol.proj.transform(defaultCoordinate, fromProjection, toProjection),
                        zoom: defaultMapZoomLevel,
                        minZoom: 2,
                        extent: olExtent
                    })
                });

                var ol3d = new olcs.OLCesium({map: map}); // map is the ol.Map instance
                ol3d.setEnabled(true);
```

I am getting these errors:

```
goog.require could not find: ol.layer.Group

Uncaught Error: goog.require could not find: ol.layer.Group
    at Object.goog.require (ol3cesium-debug.js:475)
    at ol3cesium-debug.js:1705

ReferenceError: ol is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (mapService.js:11)
    at e (angular.js:4112)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:4123)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:3981)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4112)
    at angular.js:3944
    at d (angular.js:4071)
    at e (angular.js:4103)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:4123)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular.js:3981)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The ol.js does not need to be invoked, correct?

Comment: Assuming you are using the v1.27 of the olcesium, why are you trying to load the debug version in `<script src="/resources/api/Cesium/ol3cesium-debug.js"></script>` ? If i am reading the instructions right, you should load : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
<script src="olcesium.js"></script>`

Comment: I am using ol3-cesium-v1.7 from: https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium/releases ; My application was using OpenLayers 3.82. I will try the minified version...

Comment: @Diffusion_net It wasn't necessarily the debug version, it was the old version of Cesium I was using. I tried to match up the Cesium Version with the OpenLayers version I was using (3.8x). Your comment pushed me to try the newest version, and that worked! If you answer the Question, maybe suggesting to Upgrade my Cesium Version, I will give you the answer and the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest OL Cesium version will get rid of these errors in some cases.

Comment: Just revisiting this. Not sure if I can still award the bounty, but I think if you get one more vote, at least half the bounty will be awarded.